# Che vuol dire "in seconda battuta" in questo testo?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Da poco conclusa con laurea l'esperienza alla Facoltà di Lettere, da qualche mese Ana studiava alla Scuola di giornalismo presso il Convento di Santa Monica, albergando il sogno d'andarsene un giorno in Italia. E si allegrava ogni volta nel pensarlo senza confessarlo ai genitori. L'indecisione sulla decisione che avrebbe preso Don Antonio García Royo, l'avvocato padre, la faceva muta nel rivelare il proposito. Per compiacerlo studiava il francese che le riusciva facile... e **in seconda battuta** perfezionava l'italiano.

La mia domanda è sulla locuzione "in seconda battuta" che appare in questo brano. L'unica spiegazione sul significato di questa espressione che sono riuscita a trovare su un dizionario, sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/battuta), fa riferimento al calcio. Ma questo passaggio non ha niente a che vedere con questo sport. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "in seconda battuta" nel testo sopra citato?

Comment: La “seconda battuta” c'è nel tennis: qualcosa che si tiene di riserva se va male la prima scelta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Secondariamente*, *in secondo luogo*, *solo dopo* o *dopo* (per importanza), rispetto alla prima battuta cioè quanto enunciato prima.

Io penso serva per ordinare due (raramente più) cose per le quali l'ordine è importante, cioè non un semplice elenco tra cose pari. La discriminante per l'ordinamento può essere il tempo (come nel caso del calcio), l'importanza, ma anche un rapporto di causa-effetto tra la prima e la seconda battuta.

[Qui](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1920&bih=871&tbm=bks&ei=l5k5XpeUPOyEmwXsqa3wAg&q=%22in+seconda+battuta%22+-musica&oq=%22in+seconda+battuta%22+-musica&gs_l=psy-ab.3...17334.18633.0.18908.8.8.0.0.0.0.144.618.7j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0._kEyIymQw2c) puoi trovare alcuni esempi d'uso:

- > La discesa in campo, per così dire, nel 2006, quando l'allora centrosinistra (più la sinistra che i Ds, che si accodarono **in seconda battuta**)
- > La pubblicazione, [...] ha come obiettivo l'inventario di quasi tutti i testi in volgare[...]; **in seconda battuta** si occupa anche delle tradizioni e dei riti locali
- > Non gli fu facile accettare tale notizia ma a convincerlo della realtà di quanto accadutogli, provvide innanzi tutti la fede della moglie e, **in seconda battuta**, quella del cugino di lei,
- > Da qui l'idea di dedicare una serie di articoli e **in seconda battuta** la creazione di questo ebook

L'espressione si [diffonde](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seconda+battuta&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseconda%20battuta%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cseconda%20battuta%3B%2Cc0) a partire dal 1980, le occorrenze che si trovano nei secoli precendenti sono legate al significato di battuta in ambito musicale. La diffusione del termine avviene nel 1980, sarebbe interessante trovare qualche occorrenza in qualche quotidiano sportivo visto che l'origine del termine sembra venire da lì.

**INIZIO EDIT**
Indagando meglio tramite Google Books si riescono a trovare occorrenze di *seconda battuta* anche precedenti al 1980 (data che avevo indivituato guardando il grafico).
La più interessante è sicuramente [questa](https://books.google.it/books?id=KAgxAAAAIAAJ&q=%22in+seconda+battuta%22+-musica+-armonia+-musicale&dq=%22in+seconda+battuta%22+-musica+-armonia+-musicale&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT656yhbrnAhVfwAIHHZMRD6gQ6AEIODAC) del 1962:

> [...] rimarrebbe — **in seconda battuta (per esprimerci nel linguaggio degli stadi calcistici)** — la struttura mentale dei nostri giudici, che mal si adatta alle ricerche indiziarie del processo tributario.

e [questa](https://books.google.it/books?id=SdksAQAAIAAJ&q=inauthor:%22Francesco+Calasso%22+%22seconda+battuta%22&dq=inauthor:%22Francesco+Calasso%22+%22seconda+battuta%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigg-fSirrnAhUSwAIHHbyFBj0Q6AEIKDAA) (purtroppo Google non evidenzia correttamente l'occorrenza) del 1958, che, invece, sembra avvalorare un'origine o una diffusione in ambito giuridico:

> tra verità e certezza, se nel processo civile, che tocca interessi patrimoniali, può prevalere la seconda, nel processo penale, ove si fa questione di libertà, deve prevalere la prima, anche nella forma 'relativa' o '**in seconda battuta**'

**FINE EDIT**

Scrivo qui una possibile origine del termine, è un'idea che ho avuto leggendo questo estratto [qui](https://books.google.it/books?id=mugwAAAAIAAJ&q=%22seconda+battuta%22+-musicale+-musica+-armonie&dq=%22seconda+battuta%22+-musicale+-musica+-armonie&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl_vDmpLjnAhUIJhoKHY7IABgQ6AEIPTAD):

> Che il Senato paga non di rado in termini di immagine minore e di ruolo minore la sua maggiore efficienza regolamentare. Per esempio molto spesso il Senato si trova ad esaminare **in seconda battuta** dei progetti, o **in seconda battuta il bilancio**.

Che possa l'uso di *battere* venire dall'ambito giudiziario/legislativo? e la battuta sia il colpo del martello?

Comment: Appare anche [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=4BQuAQAAIAAJ&q="seconda+battuta"&dq="seconda+battuta"&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMzYyMurjnAhUL4YUKHcJUBNs4KBDoATADegQIARAY) in un contesto giudiziario, ma forse quello della "battuta" di martello è un po' fantasioso. La cosa curiosa è che si tratti di un'espressione comune, ma che non appaia sui dizionari.

Comment: Alla voce ["scarpone"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00875.jpg) del GDLI si trova un esempio nel contesto del calcio.

Answer (score 1):

L'unico sport in cui c'è la “seconda battuta” è il tennis. Chi serve usa la prima per mettere in difficoltà l'avversario, quindi si prende qualche rischio in più.
La seconda battuta è quella un po' più sicura da eseguire quando va male la prima.

Il calcio ha ripreso la terminologia: su un attaccante pericoloso c'è sempre un difensore primario e uno che è eventualmente pronto, in seconda battuta, a intervenire se l'altro fallisce la copertura.

Il significato quindi sarebbe che, se il francese non fosse davvero servito, rimarrebbe l'italiano.

È possibile però traslare leggermente il significato letterale, intendendo qualcosa che si fa parallelamente, magari con meno impegno.

Comment: Tuttavia, il Treccani parla di calcio e non di tennis.

Comment: @Charo Mica è detto che l'estensore si intenda di tennis. La terminologia calcistica è chiaramente presa in prestito: non esiste alcuna “battuta” nel calcio. Si dice “battere una punizione”, ma questo non prevede una seconda battuta.

Answer (score 0):

In seconda battuta nel passaggio da te citato significa come attività secondaria, solitamente portata avanti contemporaneamente con la principale.

È penso mutuato dal contesto sportivo, dove esistono i concetti di prima e seconda battuta, proprio ad indicare ciò che viene prima e ciò che viene dopo.